# How to write pretty permalinks using nginx and php

Tags: php, rss, nginx

I am working on custom RSS feeds for one of my clients website "example.com" and for that the feed url takes query strings to customize the feeds like

```
http://example.com/feeds/rss_feed.php?num=20&store=2998
```

and i would like to convert these urls to

```
http://example.com/feeds/rss_feed.php/php/num/20/store/2998/
```

Any help on this matter would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create additional section in your site config. Don't forget to restart nginx after making changes.

```
location ~* ^/feeds/rss_feed.php/(.*)$ {
rewrite ^/feeds/rss_feed.php/php/num/(\d+)/store/(\d+)/$ /feeds/rss_feed.php?num=$1&store=$2 last;
}
```